# Web Request error 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, lan

Trying to GetResponse From a web site;

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace DutyPharmacy751013
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
        string responseText= reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
}
```

This code is working on win7 and LAN
 and on win8  and any of  wireless connection 
but doesn't work on win8 and LAN error: 407 Proxy authentication required.
Is there any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: do you have web proxy?

Comment: There is no proxy and Firewall , I m allowed to directly connecting to the internet

Comment: set `request.Proxy` as null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try with adding proxy credentials to request and also give network credentials

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw");

WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://myproxy.net:8080/", true)
         {
             Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw"),
             UseDefaultCredentials = false
         };

request.Proxy = webProxy;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

//rest of the code...
```

### Edit

For requests that you create, you can disable automatic proxy detection at the request level by using a null Proxy with your request

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");
request.Proxy = null;
//rest of the code
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://myproxy.net:8080/", true)
     {
         UseDefaultCredentials = false,
         Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pw")

     };
```

> Please note Correct sequence to set property {other wise failed for me}